# UPDATE table by looping through rows

Tags: mysql

I have this wrong query:

```
update product prod set 
  prod.id = (select fur.p_id 
    from furnisher fur 
    where prod.row number = fur.row number 
  )
```

What I wanna do is to set the p_id from  the first row of the table furnisher  to the id of the first row of the table product.
the same for the other elements...
I didn't find the exact syntax to execute my query (my dbms is mySql)

For example I have:

```
product |id|name |....
        |1 |prod1| 
        |2 |prod2|
```

....

```
fournitsher  p_id|activation_date|status|...
             500 |'01-01-205'    | true |
             1000|'01-01-205'    | true |
```

....

my table product should contain now :

```
product |id   |name |....
        |500  |prod1| 
        |1000 |prod2|
```

Comment: How about so many things at a time !!!

Comment: Who are down-voting the question, try to give a solution. That's more better !

Comment: give example data for product and furnisher table and expected result table content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this solution and it solves my problem :)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ROWPERROW()
BEGIN
 DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product INTO n;
 SET i=0;
 WHILE i<n DO 
  update  product set id = ( select p_id from furnisher  LIMIT i,1);
  SET i = i + 1;
 END WHILE;
End;
;;
```

then I call my procedure

```
call ROWPERROW();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want to do it for the first row, you can achieve this with `limit`. Note that since you want a first row, it should be given an order, else it is illogical as we don't really know what "first" mean. So order it by whatever you want

```
update furnisher a
join (select p_id
        from furnisher
        order by any_field
        limit 1) b using(p_id)
set a.p_id = (select id 
              from product prod
              order by any_field
              limit 1);
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I didn't get the expected result, I have all the rows with the same value !